# Unique meta descriptions for different divisions of a single page website?

Tags: seo, meta-description, single-page-application

I have a website with single page structure. It includes several categories like "About us", "Services", "Pricing" and "Contact us".

Is it necessary to write a description for each division separately? If so, how is it possible to write multiple meta descriptions for sections of a single page?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. meta descriptions are descriptions of the page, not the site as a whole. So you have to write some general description to cover everything.

However, your content is more important.

Comment: How does he actually put multiple meta descriptions on a single page site?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller As I said, he can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have a description for each maybe you could create dummy pages for each section, put all meta information in them and redirect users to the appropiate section.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html#SECTION">
```

Theoretically the search engine will read the meta while the users shouldn't even notice but I've never tried this.